# How to get other fields of objects when using aggregate and groups

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a transaction model in which I have description and status fields of transactions. Like the following

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad",
    "description": "This is a transcation",
    "invoice_id": "5795db00bfa9d366194a454d",
    "amount": 50
  },
  {
    "_id": "5795e3faf4a0fb8c1dff20ae",
    "description": "This is a transcation",
    "invoice_id": "5795db00bfa9d366194a454d",
    "amount": 100
  }
]
```

I'm using aggregation and grouping these records to find `totalAmount` of matching objects. So for this purpose I'm using this query:

```
Transaction.aggregate([{
        $match: {
            invoice: ObjectId("5795db00bfa9d366194a454d")
        }
    }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: "$_id"
            },
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            totalAmount: {
                $sum: "$amount"
            },
        }
    }
])
```

When I run this, I get the following result

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id": {
        "_id": ObjectId("5796031e07bad1d21f3af823")
    },
    "count": 1.0,
    "totalAmount": 100
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id": {
        "_id": ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad")
    },
    "count": 1.0,
    "totalAmount": 50
}
```

but I want to get all those matching objects which have specific `invoice_id` along with `totalAMount` and other fields like `description`. It should be some thing like this

```
[{
    "_id": {
        "_id": ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad")
    },
    "description": "description of first object",
    "count": 5.0,
    "totalAmount": 350
}, {
    "_id": {
        "_id": ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad")
    },
    "description": "description of second object",
    "count": 5.0,
    "totalAmount": 350
}]
```

How do I achieve this solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After few iterations of clarification (check [this code](https://gist.github.com/bearburger/55e36bb6c0412cf7c91c7fe43f0d7e26) if you are really interested) I wrote next query.

```
db.invoices.aggregate([{
    $match: {
        "invoice_id": ObjectId("5795db00bfa9d366194a454d")
    }
}, {

    $group: {
        _id: {
            _id: "$invoice_id"
        },
        count: {
            $sum: 1
        },
        info: {
            $push: {
                id: "$_id",
                amount: "$amount",
                description: "$description"

            }
        },
        totalAmount: {
            $sum: "$amount"
        }
    }
}, {
    $unwind: "$info"
}, {
    $project: {
        _id: "$info.id",
        count: "$count",
        invoice_id: "$_id",
        totalAmount: "$totalAmount",
        amount: "$info.amount",
        description: "$info.description"
    }
}])
```

What's going on here?

1. We getting all invoices with selected ID.
2. We grouping them by this ID to calculate `totalAmount` but in the same time pushing all additional information into `info` field. After that we have single document that looks like:

   ```
   {
       "_id" : {
           "_id" : "5795db00bfa9d366194a454d"
       },
       "count" : 2,
       "info" : [ 
           {
               "id" : ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad"),
               "amount" : 50,
               "description" : "This is a transcation"
           }, 
           {
               "id" : ObjectId("5796031e07bad1d21f3af823"),
               "amount" : 100,
               "description" : "FSC evening class"
           }
       ],
       "totalAmount" : 150
   }
   ```
3. We doing `$unwind` on this document that creates two documents with next structure

   ```
   {
       "_id" : {
           "_id" : "5795db00bfa9d366194a454d"
       },
       "count" : 2,
       "info" :  {
           "id" : ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad"),
           "amount" : 50,
           "description" : "This is a transcation"
       },
       "totalAmount" : 150
   }
   ```
4. The final part is projecting our structure to required one. This is simple and not need additional explanation.

Now you will be able to get results in this form:

```
    /* 1 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad"),
        "count" : 2.0,
        "totalAmount" : 150,
        "invoice_id" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5795db00bfa9d366194a454d")
        },
        "amount" : 50,
        "description" : "This is a transcation"
    }

    /* 2 */
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5796031e07bad1d21f3af823"),
        "count" : 2.0,
        "totalAmount" : 150,
        "invoice_id" : {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5795db00bfa9d366194a454d")
        },
        "amount" : 100,
        "description" : "FSC evening class"
    }
```

Comment: How can you group by  $_id as  it will be unique for each document ?

Comment: @Bhawana You ask me? This is author's code and he saying that it works as expected in his case. I'm not his boss to say him that this code has no sense.

Comment: your answer is helpful but please look into my desired result, which i mentioned in question.
i need TotalAmount with each matching object.
for example if there are two matching objects and each have amount field 50 100 respectively, than each matching object will show totalAmount = 150

Comment: @MuhammadAteek please, read update in my post. Your grouping function is wrong for your case that's why you get separate results. You need to group by `invoice_id` not by `_id`.

Comment: rather than totalAmount 50 and 100 respectively.
currently when i run your query i got results in this form
'/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5796031e07bad1d21f3af823")
    },
    "count" : 1.0,
    "totalAmount" : 100,
    "description" : "FSC evening class"
}

/* 2 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5795e3f4f4a0fb8c1dff20ad")
    },
    "count" : 1.0,
    "totalAmount" : 50,
    "description" : "This is a transcation"
}'

Comment: when i run your updated query group by invoice id i got single object with totalAmount and description of first matching object.

result are = 
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : {
        "_id" : ObjectId("5795db00bfa9d366194a454d")
    },
    "count" : 2.0,
    "totalAmount" : 150,
    "description" : "This is a transcation"
}

Comment: @MuhammadAteek You need to be clear with your question; are you grouping documents by the `invoice_id` key or by the unique `_id` field? If it's the latter then it certainly does not make sense and that's what RomanR is trying to explain in his solution.

Comment: @MuhammadAteek check **Update 2** is this what you need?

Comment: @chridam I think I understood what he want and even wrote the ugly query for this but still have no idea who may need this kind of results in real world.

Comment: Wao thanks your Update 2 Strange query is working according to my desired results. im able to get all matching objects with addition of totalAmount field. now ikm getting result in this form as i was expected

Comment: Great Done and i understand

Answer (score 0):

Changing the order of group by in the code:-

```
   db.invoices.aggregate([{


     $match: {
        "invoice_id": `ObjectId("5795db00bfa9d366194a454d")`
        }
       }, {
        $group: {
            _id: {
                _id: "$invoice_id"
            },
             description: {
                $first: "$description"
            }
            count: {
                $sum: 1
            },
            totalAmount: {
                $sum: "$amount"
            }       
        }
    }])
```